# Lower-rate LDPC codes

Tags: error-correction

What exactly does it mean to be a lower rate LDPC code? Is the ratio of information bits to parity bits being decreased? For instance, (128, 64) ldpc code is a higher rate than (90, 30) ldpc code? It is stated that a lower rate ldpc code is stronger. Thus, if I am correctly understanding the difference between lower and high rate ldpc codes, than why is a lower rate stronger? Isn't the code stronger as the number of parity bits increase? Sorry, I am kind of confused on this. Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

Comment: Code rate is the ratio of data bits to total bits (code word length)

Comment: So what exactly does a lower rate mean? Less parity bits? or less data bits?

Comment: Lower rate means more parity bits per data bit.

Comment: Similar question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/32285/5874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower code rate means less data bits for overall bits. So a lower code rate consequently also means more parity bits, causing for stronger code.